# Reinstalling a git repository as a React Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, reactjs, installation

Learning React JS, I came up to build a git repository with react components exported, to be used/installed as a package in a separate react application.

I implemented some UI Components in a git repository and installing it from git HTTP link. Like:

> "ui-components": "https://user_name@bitbucket.org/repo_path.git#branch_name"

I keep on changing the code and pushing to the remote repository, to save cost while development, I am on installing from a local directory. Like:

> "ui-components": "file:../path_to_that_repository"

Doing it, I don't have to push the changes to remote repository and can re-install it.

Now, I have to reinstall the package by deleting old copy of `node_modules/ui-components` and removing the entry from `yarn.lock` and then install it by path. 
It makes it perfect, but **takes too much of time**.

I want a single command the update that specific package by installing it from the source mentioned.

Tried the following but failed with reasons mentioned:

> - `yarn install` [it verify the yarn.lock and Says UPDATED]
> - `yarn install` ui-components [it verify the yarn.lock and Says UPDATED]
> - `yarn upgrade` [upgrade COMPLETE dependency list]
> - `yarn upgrade ui-components` [upgrade COMPLETE dependency list]
> - `yarn add ui-components` [starts finding it as a published package on `npm.js`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `npm` docs, you can mention the commit-id or the semver version (that you include in the package.json of the dependency project) to help yarn or npm identify that there is a latest version available to install.

Read the docs here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Examples:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm#semver:^5.0
git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git
git://github.com/npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
```

After understanding your concern:

Say your repository `react-plugin` is the one you want to include in your project `react-project`.

In the package.json of `react-plugin`, you specify a version, let's say 1.0.0

Next time when you update `react-plugin` make sure you update the version too.

Yarn/npm will detect that version difference and will update your local dependency according to that.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I am afraid, you got it wrong. I know how to install with git+ssh, git+http and git. What I want to learn is, Do npm or yarn has some command to facilitate like:
npm reinstall ui-components
yarn reinstall ui-components

Comment: Yes, when you specify a version in you package.json file (in the remote project), yarn will identify the current version as old and will install the latest from the remote.

Comment: Reading your comment above, I triggered of a solution. I have to update the version number of my package(remotely placed), Still confused with the command I have to use after updating the version number to a new one. Kindly guide!

Comment: That's where my previous answer comes into play. Just specify the version that you want to use. For npm package also you have to update the version in your package.json and then run `npm install`

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks for the recent edit in your answer. I worked!.